# Is HPKP a alternative to DNSSEC?

Tags: dnssec, hpkp

Using the Public Key Pinning header the user will only trust in my SSL Certificate, supposedly.

If I use only the HPKP and the certificate is safe, the attacker not got it, still possible the attacker do a MITM or something like that?

In my mind, probably wrong, the attacker still able to *redirect* the user to another location, but he not have the cert, so the HPKP will block it. This will prevent the user to *consume the content* from the *fake server*.

Have a reason to use HPKP + DNSSEC?

Answer (score 1):

HPKP is TOFU(Trust On First Use). So if a user system compromised, but the browser still retain the pin, when the malware redirect the url request to a fake certificate to their phony proxy. the browser will show error like "SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN" (varied depends on browser).

However, there is some site doing it wrongly, e.g. as report by Netcraft : [HTTP Public Key Pinning: You’re doing it wrong!](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2016/03/30/http-public-key-pinning-youre-doing-it-wrong.html)

In addition, because its TOFU nature, HPKP is not bulletproof to MiTM.

However, if you have an webapp/mobile app that inherit pin for HPKP, then your webapp are protected from MiTM attack if implemented properly